# why after truncate the table space not returned when view object size in tablespace?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am always use TRUNCATE TABLE to free up space and always the space returned to free space

when I check the free space in oracle tablespace I found the free space increased always

I am using TOAD program to

```
TRUNCATE TABLE
```

But this time different I truncated 2 tables but its not free the table space and when I checked

the table size after truncated its still same size used before around 400 MB

why its not free the space , and how to free the space table already truncated and no data in it.

also I moved the table to another tablespace after truncate but its moved with same size

```
ALTER TABLE CAS_NOSHOW MOVE TABLESPACE   TRNG;
```

how to free up space please your help .

I am using oracle 10g database

Comment: No, truncate doesn't release anything. The reason why truncate is quick is because it simply moves the High Water Mark in the table, effectively back to the start of the table so that it appears there is no longer any data in it.

Comment: @Pugzly but i am using truncate table command from 15 years and always after truncate when check the free space its show the table size 0 MB , but this time still show 400 MB , how to solve this and return table size to 0 MB ?

Comment: Truncate table DOESN'T resize the data files it only moves the high water mark. If you want to reclaim space see my demo below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to recover space above and below the high water mark you can shrink the table.

To do this you need to have row movement enabled.

```
 create table t as
     select rownum x, lpad('x', 500, 'x') xx from dual connect by level <= 10000;
/

-- ALTER TABLE t SHRINK SPACE CHECK;

 select bytes from user_segments
    where  segment_name = 'T';
/

 delete t where x <= 9900;
/

select bytes from user_segments
 where  segment_name = 'T';
/

 alter table t enable row movement;
/

 alter table t shrink space CASCADE;
/

 select bytes from user_segments
    where  segment_name = 'T';
```

Comment: Thank you so much its working now enable row movement then shrink space :)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked out. Fyi, if you are really on 10G you should upgrade as that version has been desupprted for years

Comment: yes I told the company to upgrade thank you